# Undefined method `has?' for Sass::Util:Module (NoMethodError) - Error on Debian with Ruby, Sass, Compass

Tags: ruby, linux, sass, compass, nomethoderror

I searched for a solution to the following problem, but I couldn't find anything. So I hoped that you could help me. Thank you.

I have:

- **Debian Stretch** (distro: `Debian GNU/Linux 9.7`, kernel: `Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 (x86_64)`);
- **Apache NetBeans 10 (incubating)** - the snap installed from https://snapcraft.io/netbeans;
- **PHP 7.1**.

I installed (by inspiring myself from [this](https://blog.42mate.com/how-to-install-compass-on-debian/) page:

- **Ruby** (with: `sudo apt install ruby-full`);
- **Sass** (with `sudo gem install sass`);
- **Compass** (with `sudo gem install compass`);

and checked their versions:

```
# ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

# sass --version
Ruby Sass 3.7.3

# compass --version
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2019 Chris Eppstein
```

Please note that I have null experience with Ruby.

I have the following **NetBeans settings**:

*) In the tab *"Tools > Options > HTML/JS > CSS Preprocessors"*:

```
Sass Path: /usr/local/bin/sass
```

I also tried:

```
Sass Path: /usr/local/bin/scss
```

*) In the tab *"File > Project Properties > CSS Preprocessors > Sass"*:

```
Input: /web/src/Application/assets/scss
Output: /web/public/assets/css
Compiler Options: --compass -E "UTF-8" --trace --no-cache
```

**Backtrace:**

When I tried to compile the *.scss* files (in order to create the corresponding *.css* files) I received an error for each of them. This is the backtrace for the first *.scss* file:

```
"/usr/local/bin/sass" "--cache-location" "/home/<my-username>/snap/netbeans/common/cache/10.0/sass-compiler" "--sourcemap=none" "--compass" "-E" "UTF-8" "--trace" "--no-cache" "<my-path-to-project-root>/web/src/Application/assets/scss/fonts.scss" "<my-path-to-project-root>/web/public/assets/css/fonts.css"
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/urls.rb:5:in `has?': undefined method `has?' for Sass::Util:Module (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  hash
               Hash
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/urls.rb:9:in `included'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.7.3/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:627:in `include'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.7.3/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:627:in `include'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions.rb:23:in `<module:Functions>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core.rb:68:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.7.3/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:238:in `load_compass'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.7.3/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:49:in `process_result'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.7.3/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:50:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.7.3/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:18:in `parse!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.7.3/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/sass:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
Done.
```

***urls.rb* file**:

This is the beginning content of the file specified in the backtrace (*/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/urls.rb*):

```
module Compass::Core::SassExtensions::Functions::Urls


  def self.has?(base, instance_method)
    Sass::Util.has?(:instance_method, base, instance_method)
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, StylesheetUrl) unless has?(base, :stylesheet_url)
    base.send(:include, FontUrl) unless has?(base, :font_url)
    base.send(:include, ImageUrl) unless has?(base, :image_url)
    base.send(:include, GeneratedImageUrl) unless has?(base, :generated_image_url)
  end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### The problem:

The problem resided in the fact, that I installed the Debian's package `ruby-full`, along with Sass and Compass as ruby gems, e.g. using the *gem* command-line tool.

#### The solution:

By default, Debian 9.7 (*Stretch*) has the Ruby interpreter installed (version 2.3). The package name is `ruby2.3`. In order to be able to correctly compile .scss files and use the functions provided by Compass, only the packages `ruby-sass` and `ruby-compass` must be additionaly installed.

#### Followed steps:

***I) First, using Terminal, I proceeded with the uninstallation of the previously wrongly installed libraries:***

I uninstalled the package `ruby-full`:

```
$ sudo apt purge ruby-full
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

I uninstalled the Sass and Compass gems:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall compass
$ sudo apt autoremove

$ sudo gem uninstall sass
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

***II) Then I proceeded with the installation of the new packages:***

I checked the status of the Debian's default Ruby version:

```
$ apt list ruby2.3*
ruby2.3/stable,now 2.3.3-1+deb9u4 amd64 [installed]
ruby2.3-dev/stable,now 2.3.3-1+deb9u4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ruby2.3-doc/stable,now 2.3.3-1+deb9u4 all [installed,automatic]
```

I installed the new packages:

```
$ apt update
$ apt install ruby-sass
$ apt install ruby-compass
```

I checked the versions of both installed packages:

```
$ sass --version
Sass 3.4.23 (Selective Steve)

$ compass --version
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2019 Chris Eppstein
```

I checked the locations of the installed executable files:

```
$ which sass
/usr/bin/sass

$ which compass
/usr/bin/compass
```

***III) In the end, in Netbeans, in the tab `Tools > Options > HTML/JS > CSS Preprocessors`, I set the `Sass Path` to `/usr/bin/sass`.***

That was it. The Sass files are correctly compiled and the Compass functions are correctly recognized and called.

Answer (score 4):

Found this searching for the same error message. I was able to resolve the issue by switching the version of sass on my local from `sass-3.7.4` to `sass-3.4.25 (Selective Steve)`.

Another possible fix for this error message.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your contribution.